# Javascript changing function trouble

Tags: javascript

The code below is how it was originally

```
   function getRandomEmail() {
        const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 200000)+1;
        return `User${randomNumber}@example.com`
    }
```

Instead of a random number generated and inserted I am trying to have an list of words added infront of the @example.com

like so

```
function getRandomEmail() {
var emailname = "testing testing2 testing3".split(" ");
return `User$(Math.floor(Math.random() * emailname.split)+ @example.com`
```

The output I'm getting now while running the script is

BAD_EMAIL: that email is invalid

did I miss anything ???

Comment: The last row is incorrect. `emailname.split`. emailname was already split the row above. Probably `emailname.length`.

Comment: There's **lots** wrong with that (I can spot 4 completely different errors without blinking). Stop trying to put it all on one line. Store intermediate values in variables. Log them as you go. Then you'll find it a lot easier to spot your errors.

Comment: Have you just tried for instance to _display_ some examples generated ? like with console.log() ? `console.log(getRandomEmail())`

Comment: So many errors in your code thats impossible to know for us what you exacly want to do.

Comment: Where is that `BAD_EMAIL: that email is invalid ` coming from? There's no logging in that function.

1. `getRandomEmail` function is missing closing `}`
2. `emailname.split` does not evaluate to a number, yet you're trying to do multiplication.
3. You're trying to do string template? It needs to be like this I think: `return \`User${Math.floor(Math.random() * email.length)}@example.com\``

Answer (score 1):

**1** `emailname` is already an array after the `split` in the initialization. Now what you need is it's `length`

**2** to insert the variable use `${..}`, not `$()`

```
function getRandomEmail() {
  var emailname = "testing testing2 testing3".split(" ");
  return `User${Math.floor(Math.random() * emailname.length)}@example.com`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`emailname` is an array of string "**testing testing2 testing3**".

You don't need to again split.

Also, if you are using **back-ticks (`)** then you access variables/constant using `${variableName}`, and **NOT BY** `$(variableName)`

```js
function getRandomEmail() {
    var emailname = "testing testing2 testing3".split(" ");
    const randomElement = emailname[Math.floor(Math.random() * emailname.length)];
    return `User${randomElement}@example.com`;
}

console.log(getRandomEmail());
```

## UPDATE

1. First, generate a random index from the array.

   `const randomElementIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * emailname.length);`
2. Then find the element corresponds to that index.

   `const randomElement = emailname[randomElementIndex];`;
3. Now, you need to remove that element for the array.

   `emailname.splice(randomElementIndex , 1);`
   // This will return you an array without the element you have used.

So now your `getRandomEmail()` can be as follows.

```js
function getRandomEmail(emailName) {
        //Generating random element
        const randomElementIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * emailName.length);

        // Getting random name based on random element.
        const randomElement = emailName[randomElementIndex];

        // Poping out that random element from an array
        emailName.splice(randomElementIndex , 1);
        return `User${randomElement}@example.com`;
    }

    var emailName = "testing testing2 testing3".split(" ");
    console.log(getRandomEmail(emailName));
```

Suppose you are having **NO** Database from you are getting this name strings.
In that case, you can save the string **"testing testing2 testing3"** in [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to store the string on the user's device and use it whenever you want to generate a new email.

So now the procedure will be
1) Save the string in the user's device. 
  `window.localStorage.setItem("names-list-string", "testing testing2 testing3");`
2) Now fetch the string from `localStorage` and split in to array.
   `var emailName = window.localStorage.getItem("names-list-string").split(" ");`
3) Pass the emailName array to **getRandomEmail()**
   `getRandomEmail(emailName);`
4) We have to modify the **getRandomEmail()** a little.
   Now when we **splice()** and an array we convert back it to string and update the localStorage.
   `emailName.splice(randomElementIndex , 1);`
   `let emailString = emailName.join(" ");`
   `window.localStorage.setItem("names-list-string", emailString);`

Comment: That does the trick, Now I have to figure out how to remove the 'names' from the array, as .splice doesn't work with back-ticks

Comment: If you need to `splice` the array, probably you want to init it outside the function. inside the function it will just create new array any time, so the splice do nothing. so probably you need something like this: 
`var emailname = "testing testing2 testing3".split(" ");
function getRandomEmail() {
    const randomElement = emailname.splice(Math.floor(Math.random() * emailname.length), 1);
    return \`User${randomElement}@example.com\`;
}`

Comment: Could you please check the 'answer' I have found to my problem above?

Comment: @Decimo can you please elaborate on what exactly you are looking for?

Comment: @NotABot basically, grab a 'word' from an array and use that to create an email/name and never use that 'word' again. So an array of 1000 will go down to 0 eventually. and be able to save the used 'word'.

Comment: @Decimo I have updated the answer, hope this solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I think the following is good as far my knowledge goes. Is it correct ? Did I miss anything ?

edit: doesn't function as expected. the same 'word' from the array gets used multiple times and the array is never emptied.

```js
function getRandomEmail() {
        var emailname = "test1 test2 test3".split(" ");
        const randomElement = emailname[Math.floor(Math.random() * emailname.length)];
        const index = emailname.indexOf(randomElement);
          if (index > -1){ emailname.splice(index, 1);}
          console.log(emailname);
          if (emailname && emailname.length > 0) {
       console.log('emailname is not empty.');
       return `${randomElement}@example.com`;
    }else{
       console.log('emailname is empty.');
    }
        return ("no mail available");
    }
    
     console.log(getRandomEmail());
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution that uses [randojs.com](https://randojs.com) for readability.

```js
function getRandomEmail(){
  return rando(["accounting", "sales", "hr"]).value + "@dundermifflin.com";
}

console.log(getRandomEmail());
```

```html
<script src="https://randojs.com/1.0.0.js"></script>
```